# How to add grid graph as a background of one graph plot?

Tags: python, csv, grid

I want to add grid graph as a background of a signal plot generated from the following code?

```
dff = pd.read_csv("abc.csv")
x = dff['A']
times = np.arange(len(x))/360
plt.subplot(121)
plt.plot(times, x)
plt.tight_layout()
plt.show()
```

What should I change in this code. Can anyone help me out.Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

To add gridlines to PyPlot plots, you can use the `grid()` tool:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
plt.subplot(121)
plt.plot()
plt.tight_layout()
plt.grid(axis='both')
plt.show()
```

[image: example output graph]

You can see more about its arguments [here](https://matplotlib.org/3.2.1/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.grid.html).

Note that in matplotlib you might have a better time using figures with the "axes" object, rather than the functional interface.  E.g.:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
fig, ax = plt.subplots()
ax.plot()
ax.grid()
```

This allows you to index `axs` objects like lists, and pass plots as arguments.

Comment: No problem, please accept it as a correct answer if you can